# How to include Progress Bar Before Going To Next Activity?

Tags: android

**Am working on an android app in which there are list of activites.while launching any activity its talking sometime.So m thinking to include the progess bar till the next activity  launched.**

I have gone through a lot of question on progress bar but m not getting the exact solution.So,can any one suggest me the best way to integrate progress bar in my App.

I am Sharing My code and the logCat its not working.

```
  package com.example.progress;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.ProgressDialog;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private ProgressDialog progress;
  Button Button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
     progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
     Button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

      Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                     progress.setMessage("Please Wait Loading...");
               progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
               progress.setIndeterminate(true);
            progress.show();
             new Thread() 
             {

                 public void run() 
                 {

                     Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
                     startActivity(i);
                     progress.dismiss();
                 }

             }.start();


                    break;
        }

        }
    });
    }
}

  LOgCat Error :::
  -----------   



       01-27 17:23:19.094: D/AndroidRuntime(13666): Shutting down VM
       01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666): Process: com.example.progress, PID:  13666
       01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.progress/com.example.progress.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
        01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
      01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
      01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
      01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
     01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
      01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:702)
      01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666): Caused by:   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void  android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
       01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666):     at com.example.progress.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
       01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
       01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
      01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666):  at      android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
       01-27 17:23:19.095: E/AndroidRuntime(13666):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: http://www.geeks.gallery/horizontal-and-circular-progress-bar-in-android/

Comment: Please show the code of `Second.class` because it looks like there is heavy work being done in Second class on `Main UI Thread`. If that's the case then you have to move the heavy operation on `AsyncTask` and show the `progress bar` for that. Let me know which is the scenario?

Comment: no heavy work is there in the second class i just shared the demo code the way m trying to include a progress bar.The scenario is like as m launching any activity ,the progress should come out till the activity is taking time to be launched.

Answer (score 1):

How about starting the `Progressbar` when you click on the `Button` to go to the next activity or however you launch it, and then stop/close the bar in `onPause()`?

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose your activity display simple list view

```
 private ProgressBar mProgBar;
mProgBar= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarMain);
mProgBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //before doing your desired operation

/*     do your stuff here  populate your listview     */


mProgBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //hide the progressbar
//display your list here
```

Comment: So basically i have to include this code before launching the other activity.

Answer (score 0):

try to edit your `onClick()` as below to see the `progressBar` working
Because your `progressBar` is belong to current `Activity` so when you start another `Activity` you are not able to see the `progress bar`

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                     progress.setMessage("Please Wait Loading...");
               progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
               progress.setIndeterminate(true);
            progress.show();
             new Thread() 
             {

                 public void run() 
                 {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                     Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
                     startActivity(i);
                     progress.dismiss();
                 }

             }.start();


                    break;
        }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Din Thai what i have to edit in onclick method let me know.....u hv just copied the same code.

Comment: I had added the Thread.sleep on to your implementation. It will makes the progress bar become visible

Comment: you mean the progress dialog still invisible ?

Comment: code have  some error .Application is getting crashed everytime.

Comment: please show me the log cat of Error. it'll help. We should detect the root of the problem base on the log

Comment: your Button object get null. Change the name of the Button to mButton and your activity can not find the object with id R.id.button1. Show your layout file, plz